# Laravel 5 relationships

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.1. I have a database with two tables:

The first, the companies table:

```
|-------|--------------|
|   id  | company_name |
|-------|--------------|
|   1   |  Company A   |
|-------|--------------|
|   2   |  Company B   |
|-------|--------------| 
|   3   |  Company A1  |
|-------|--------------|
|   4   |  Company B1  |
|-------|--------------|
|   5   |  Company B2  |
|-------|--------------|
```

The second, the relationships table:

```
|--------|----------------------------|
|   id   |  company_id  |  parent_id  |
|--------|--------------|-------------|
|   1    |       1      |     null    |
|--------|--------------|-------------|
|   2    |       2      |     null    |
|--------|--------------|-------------|
|   3    |       3      |      1      |     
|--------|--------------|-------------|
|   4    |       4      |      2      |
|--------|--------------|-------------|
|   5    |       5      |      2      |
|--------|--------------|-------------|
```

Now an user selects a `company_id` from the relationships table, let's say 4 (Company B1) I would like to display this result:

```
Company B (your selection's main company)
   Company B1 (your selection)
   Company B2 (your selection related company)
```

Or if the user selects 1 (Company A) this result should be displayed:

```
Company A (your selection)
   Company A1 (your selection children company)
```

In simple words, I need to determine if the selected company in the relationships table has parent and/or children and where the current selection is positioned (as a child or parent).
Companies that have `null` as `parent_id` can't have parents, only children.

What I have tried so far:

My relationships `Model`

```
class CompaniesRelationships extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'companies_relationships';
   public function scopeGetParent($query, $companyID)
   {
      return $query->whereCompany_id($companyID)->select('parent_id');
   }
}
```

My companies `Model`

```
class Companies extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'companies';
}
```

And in my controller

```
class CompaniesController extends Controller
{
   public function getCompaniesDetails()
   {
      $companyID = Input::get('companyID');
      $Company = \App\Models\CompaniesRelationships::getparent($companyID)
                 ->leftJoin('companies', 'companies.id', '=', 'companies_relationships.company_id')
                 ->get();
   }
}
```

And I would have added another scope in the relationships `Model` to get the children and then make some PHP conditionnal statements to get the position.

But I think there is a better solution than selecting the parent and then the children in different queries and I believe a single query could do the trick but I can't figure out how to make it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should define the one-to-many relation between company and another company, see: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: https://github.com/etrepat/baum   could help you with this

Answer (score 0):

Laravel is giving its best to maintain the relationship first of all you need to have 2 model or you can say two table for relation and the respestive columns now you need to specify whether it has relation of one to one or one to many or many to many then you can simple specify it on model. As your tables are not specific tables so you can see the example like relation between users table and questions table  relation here is one to many . One user can have many question while one question is belong to the user now  In my Questions model the realtion looks like `public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }`

now in the user model my code looks like 
        `return $this->hasMany('App\Questions');
    }`

be sure you have maintained foreign key while migrating :) for more you can see here http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#relationships hope this would help

Comment: This is what I have used but it's only a part of the question, I needed to know the selected id's position in the tree. https://github.com/etrepat/baum is great and helped me a lot for that.